# How to make the parent git folder always point to latest commit whenever there is a new commit in child module(submodule)

Tags: git, commit, git-submodules

Every time I push a commit to the submodule I need to update the parent repo to the latest commit in the submodule. Is there any automatic way to do that in the remote?

Every time push a commit in the submodule repo I want the parent to automatically point to the latest commit of the child repo. Please suggest if it's possible and how?

Comment: No, there is no automatic way to do this. You must make a new superproject commit that uses the new submodule commit. (You could write a tiny bit of code that does that, but it's not included with Git.)

Comment: You need to  write a  post-commit hook telling the parent repo to update the link to the dsubmodule

Comment: Hi @Ivan, could you share some reference for this post-commit hook which could help me do this 
1.go to a checked-out parent repository
2. execute git submodule update --remote: that would update all submodules to their latest master (by default) commit.
3. add, commit, and push

Answer (score 1):

There is a special situation that can happen when pulling superproject updates: it could be that the upstream repository has changed the URL of the submodule in the .gitmodules file in one of the commits you pull. This can happen for example if the submodule project changes its hosting platform. In that case, it is possible for git pull --recurse-submodules, or git submodule update, to fail if the superproject references a submodule commit that is not found in the submodule remote locally configured in your repository. In order to remedy this situation, the git submodule sync command is required:

copy the new URL to your local config

git submodule sync --recursive

update the submodule from the new URL

git submodule update --init --recursive here

You need to run this code as git hook like on push, on pull, on merge, etc

Reference-

https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules